# Using HybridAuth to connect to OpenID Connect provider

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, identityserver3, openid-connect, hybridauth

Im using CakePHP 3.2 and [CakePHP HybridAuth plugin](https://github.com/ADmad/CakePHP-HybridAuth), and Im trying to connect to OpenID Connect provider(which is implemented in IdentityServer 3). On [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.github.io/hybridauth/) configuration examples for connecting to OpenID Connect they are using only `openid_identifier` as a parameter, but what about client id and other parameters that are needed for OpenID to work? Examples for OpenID provider can be found [here](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/IDProvider_info_OpenID.html). Is it possible to use HybridAuth to connect to my own OpenID connect provider, and if not, is there any other solution to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit more specific (and link to the content that you refer to) if you want us to help.

Comment: @PieterEnnes I added more details to the question

Comment: I need also this solutions